# install gem command locally

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems

How do I install the `gem` command locally?

I'm on a shared hosting, the machine has `ruby` installed, but I need to get the gem command installed to `$HOME/opt` so I can install ruby modules like sass.

Comment: have the answer been helpful, or not, if not which problem you have encountered with?

Answer (score -1):

You can install [*rvm*](https://rvm.io) into the **$HOME/.rvm** folder, and use with it non-system rubies, and gemsets, just install required ruby, and create newly named gemset from within the *rvm* session. All of them will be stored in yuor home folder.

In case if you strictly with to use **$HOME/opt**, you shell install the *rvm*, then move its folder to the **$HOME/opt**, set properly *PATH* environment variable up, and fix call to *rvm* in the **$HOME/.bash_profile**.